# Which mysql construct is faster?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT ... WHERE COL IN(A,B) 

or 

SELECT ... WHERE (COL = A or COL = B)
```

I'm trying to find out what are the differences between the two constructs? 
Would there be significant performance gains either way if utilized on resultsets that are nearing the 1 million mark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql> describe select * from users where id = 1 or id = 2;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe select * from users where id in (1,2);
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Judging from `DESCRIBE` statement's output - they are identical.

Comment: To compound on this, the query optimizer should reduce these two simple examples to exactly the same query.

If your example is more complex, you'll want to use DESCRIBE/EXPLAIN on the query to get info about how things are being executed.

Comment: Do you **know** that the same query plan is chosen for a query on the user's table, as will be chosen on a table containing millions of records? I'm not sure your exmple convinces me.

Comment: I hope (but without much hope) that the DESCRIBE wasn't done on an empty table, signifying nothing.

Comment: These queries were run on a table with 340k records.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference between using

```
col = A or col = B
```

and

```
col IN (8,7,5,2,....)
```

The mysql range optimizer optimizes the IN query by computing a sorted list of (8,7,5,2,....) which is then used to construct the corresponding SEL_TREE.

So there is no performance difference as both would be doing a range scan on the index.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a small example:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.1.41-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SET @qwe=5;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe IN (10,5));
+--------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe IN (10,5)) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    0 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (3.52 sec)

mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe = 10 OR @qwe = 5);
+---------------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe = 10 OR @qwe = 5) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (5.91 sec)
```

And:

```
mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe IN (10,1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5));
+------------------------------------------------------+
| BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe IN (10,1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5)) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    0 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (6.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000, @qwe = 10 OR @qwe = 1 OR @qwe = 9
    ->   OR @qwe = 2 OR @qwe = 8 OR @qwe = 3 OR @qwe = 7 OR @qwe = 4
    ->   OR @qwe = 6 OR @qwe = 5) as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
1 row in set (20.20 sec)
```

Mind the duration in parentheses.